# SpriteNode position delay using update function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a character of type `SKSpriteNode()`and you can choose from an array of hats for him to wear, also of type `SKSpriteNode()`.

I have used the `override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)` to keep the position of the hat on the characters head: `hat.position = char.position`.

The problem is that as he jumps, the hat is lagging behind a little, which looks funny on his way down but on his way up it doesn't look right.

I would rather avoid having to add textures for all his frames for each type of hat as there will be a lot. Is there a way to make the function update more frequently to fix this problem? Or is there a more appropriate way to handle this situation?

**Solution, Thanks to Whirlwind**

Instead of using `self.addChild(hat)` and then updating the position,
just use `char.addChild(hat)` and it works perfectly... so simple.

Comment: Add a hat to character node. Then just change hat's texture. That should work. In this case there is no need to change hat's position at all. It will move along with the character.

Comment: I can't believe i didn't think of that, you're amazing!

Comment: Regarding the position, put the position setting code in `didSimulatePhysics` which happens after physics has been calculated (and hence jumps work nicely).  Whirlwind's direction is still the better way though in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the input Gliderman, this worked great too.